# Search engine optimization for text with different colors

Tags: seo, search-engines, optimization

We're trying to do SEO on our company website. Our company logo is just text (in image form), but has two colors in it. Our company name appears a lot in our website's text/copy. For example, the sentence,

```
This is our company name: COMPANY.
```

is coded as,

```
This is our company name:

<span class="logo_black">COMP</span>
<span class="logo_red">A</span>
<span class="logo_black">N</span>
<span class="logo_red">Y</span>
```

Is it search engine friendly? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't very friendly. Search Engines can understand the content but might not be able to consider COMPANY as one single word.

My suggestion is to use JavaScript.
You can write something like

```
This is our company name: <span class="company">COMPANY</span>.
```

Then use JavaScript to

- load the content of the `.company` class
- split/stylize the content of the element according to your custom rules

If you already use a JavaScript framework like jQuery, it shouldn't be much work.

Comment: +1 Google and Bing will treat each portion wrapped in a `<span>` as a separate word (learned this the hard way on a personal site when using span tags to create drop caps)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Java or CSS, but I know SEO marketing.

I would recommend adding some alt text to the logo with your company name and slogan in the alt text.  Chances are, people aren't necessarily searching for YOUR COMPANY, but rather a problem, which your company has the solution to.  Think of your keywords as what the user is searching for.

Comment: "SEO marketing" - marketing search engine optimization services..?

Answer (score 0):

Google SEO Guide [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf&ei=Ik0IU9_WOKnJiAeOx4CgDg&usg=AFQjCNEMj8KHxhxQz9cMLoMxMDiLdrAbJw&sig2=juu5-iwsFEU4FCeszOd7lw) . But the span with image what you asked in your question won't get more changes in your SEO, You website content with meta will give you the real effect in SEO.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more your answer, right now seems a bit vague or disconnected. Plus, it's good that you link that manual from Google, but can you point any specific part from the manual that helps to solve the situation?